# appium how to check iOS application is running on background or minimized or closed?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

how to check iOS application is running on background or minimized or closed while using Appium Automation?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to do that what you can check it with invisibility of any element of your app.